# How to perform efficient Bulk update in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, bulkupdate

I just spent the last one hour reading on stack but did not find answer for my use case. It's pretty straightforward though.

I have a table which will have like 5000 entries max. The table has 10+ columns. One of the column values needs to be updated every 3 minutes for all the 5000 entries. And the value to be updated is different for each row.

I am looking for an efficient UPDATE (Bulk) operation I can do which possibly splits the operation in smaller bulks. Please note that the operation needs to be as efficient as possible. Also the operation should block any simultaneous reads for the least time possible.

Suggestions ?

Comment: Sorry but this is still vague: _One of the column values needs to be updated every 3 minutes for all the 5000 entries. And the value to be updated is different for each row._

Comment: @suguspnk The table stores all the parking zones of a city. so there are like 5000 zones in the city. Now each bay has a property called 'Availability' which indicates how many more vehicles can the zone accommodate. And the availability needs to be updated every 3 minutes (so as to avoid user getting stale data). I guess this clears things up.

Comment: can you explain with some examples  and also elaborate on whether the whole column changes totally,what are your preferences ,do you want the table to be locked for the duration...?

Comment: Do you have another relevant source of data that you haven't mentioned yet? Like another table or data file that you are using to update the availability column of your parking zone.

Comment: @TheGameiswar As I mentioned in my question, only one column value changes for all the rows. All the other column values are untouched. Also I want to take a lock as narrow as possible so that simultaneous reads are not blocked which means i would like to avoid table locking as far as possible (row or page locking is something i might need)

Comment: @suguspnk The data to be updated (that's the new data) is already in memory in a map data structure. I guess that answered your last question

Comment: Table is not that huge and further you are updating all the columns..so i would suggest below options


**update.write**,if only some part of column value changes.This logs very efficiently

**EX:**  

    update table
    set col.write('value to be used in update',start at,number of characters).



**normal update**,with everything wrapped in a transaction.Benefit of this is logging overhead will be less,but then again,this will lock the whole table for the duration .

Comment: @TheGameiswar I am not updating all the columns, just one column for all the rows. I quite not get your solution btw.

Comment: sorry,i meant all rows.i think,try proceeding with normal update,since the table is not that huge and also i dont believe lock escalation wont be triggered due to 5000 rows

Comment: @TheGameiswar How about if there are simultaneous reads ? Will there by any kind of lock escalation in that case ?

Comment: single transaction acquiring more than 5000 locks will lock the table,but there more to it and it also depends on many factors( i cant recall much now),i would not worry about locking and blocking,since this table is very small and i would try to solve issues as they appear in this case and proceed with normal update

Comment: Use snapshot isolation for the readers. Problem solved.